# Trigger Types in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, triggers

I was going through the different type of Triggers from **[here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25600/Triggers-Sql-Server)**

This article is sayiong triggers are classified into two main types:-

- After Triggers  // This fires after row is inserted/updated/deleted
- Instead Of Triggers  // This fires before the row is inserted/updated/deleted

In which category does the following trigger fit?

```
create trigger TriggerName
on TableName For Insert
As
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx):

> AFTER is the default when FOR is the only keyword specified.